# How to output JSON as [{"A",10.5}] instead of [{"X":"A","Y":10.5}]

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

By using the code below, I got a JSON string in this format:

```
[{"X":"A","Y":10.5},{"X":"B","Y":11.5},{"X":"C","Y":12.5},{"X":"D","Y":13.5}]
```

But my requirement is this:

```
[{"A",10.5},{"B",11.5},{"C",12.5},{"D",13.5}]
```

How can I get the result I need?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim RegisteredUsers As New List(Of Person)()
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    RegisteredUsers.Add(New Person With {.X = "A", .Y = 10.5})
    RegisteredUsers.Add(New Person With {.X = "B", .Y = 11.5})
    RegisteredUsers.Add(New Person With {.X = "C", .Y = 12.5})
    RegisteredUsers.Add(New Person With {.X = "D", .Y = 13.5})
    Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(RegisteredUsers)
    Response.Write(serializedResult)
End Sub
```

Comment: What you're trying to output is not JSON. It's basically CSV with braces.

Answer (score 1):

@Steven Liekens is correct: your "required output" as stated in your question is not actually valid JSON. (You can check it at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)). Since you probably do want valid JSON, I'm assuming you either meant this:

```
[{"A":10.5},{"B":11.5},{"C":12.5},{"D":13.5}]
```

Or you meant this:

```
[["A",10.5],["B",11.5],["C",12.5],["D",13.5]]
```

You can get the first output by changing your code to build a `List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Double))` like this:

```
Dim RegisteredUsers As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Double))()
Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
RegisteredUsers.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, Double) From {{"A", 10.5}})
RegisteredUsers.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, Double) From {{"B", 11.5}})
RegisteredUsers.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, Double) From {{"C", 12.5}})
RegisteredUsers.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, Double) From {{"D", 13.5}})
Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(RegisteredUsers)
Response.Write(serializedResult)
```

To get the second output, you would need to build a `List(Of List(Of Object))` instead, like this:

```
Dim RegisteredUsers As New List(Of List(Of Object))()
Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
RegisteredUsers.Add(New List(Of Object) From {"A", 10.5})
RegisteredUsers.Add(New List(Of Object) From {"B", 11.5})
RegisteredUsers.Add(New List(Of Object) From {"C", 12.5})
RegisteredUsers.Add(New List(Of Object) From {"D", 13.5})
Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(RegisteredUsers)
Response.Write(serializedResult)
```